# how to interact with an external script(program)

Tags: python, bash, externalinterface, interaction

there is a script that expects keyboard input, 
i can call that script with os.system('./script') in python,

how is it possible to send back an input to the script from another calling script?

**update:**

the script is:

```
$ cat script
#!/usr/bin/python
for i in range(4):
        name=raw_input('enter your name')
        print 'Welcome %s :) ' % name
```

when i try without a for loop, it works but it shows the output only  when the script quits.

```
>>> p = subprocess.Popen('./script',stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> p.communicate('navras')
enter your nameWelcome navras :)
```

when i try it with the foor loop, it throws error, How to display the statements interactive as and when the stdout is updated with new print statements

```
>>> p.communicate('megna')
enter your nameWelcome megna :)
enter your nameTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "./script", line 3, in <module>
    name=raw_input('enter your name')
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
(None, None)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use subprocess instead of os.system:

```
p = subprocess.Popen('./script',stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate('command')
```

its not testet

Comment: These references should give more detail:

http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html
http://jimmyg.org/blog/2009/working-with-python-subprocess.html

In the example above, you probably also want to add the argument `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`. The communicate function should return a tuple `(stdout, stderr)` with the data sent to each of these descriptors.

You an also try `p.stdin.write()` and `p.stdout.readline()`. Really, you can treat `p.stdin` and `p.stdout` just as you would any other file object :)

Comment: when i try it with the foor loop, it throws error, How to display the statements interactive as and when the stdout is updated with new print statements.

>>> p.communicate('megna')
enter your nameWelcome megna :)
enter your nameTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "./script", line 3, in <module>
    name=raw_input('enter your name')
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
(None, None)

Answer (score -2):

In fact, os.system and os.popen are now deprecated and subprocess is the recommended way to handle all sub process interaction.